# Asking about the Coverage summary in Unit test of angular 2?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, karma-coverage

When I run test in angular 2 and I see a few keywords output on console command in Coverage Summary section as `Statements`, `Branches`, `Functions`....

[image]

And I don't know exactly what is it?

Any help explain this for me, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

- **Statement**: I think [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) does a pretty goo d job explaining what a statement it. The coverage tests that all your statements are getting hit.
- **Branch**: When you use conditionals it create branches

  ```
  if (condition) {
    doThis();       // this is a branch
  } else {
    doThat();       // this is a branch
  }
  ```

  Is your testing hitting all the branches?
- **Functions**: The functions that you declare.

  ```
  class SomeClas {
    methodOne() {}
    methodTwo() {}
  }

  it('..', () => {
    new SomeClass().methodOne();
  })
  ```

  `SomeClass` has two methods, but only one is getting tested. 50%. If you either explicitly call `methodTwo` in your test *or* `methodOne` calls `methodTwo`, your coverage goes to 100%
- **Lines:**: The lines of code, checks to see if all the lines of code are being hit.